# mysql - many to many query from bridge table

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, many-to-many, aggregate-functions

i have a task to complete. there is a many to many relationship. the bridge table has been made which looks like

```
    left id     right id
  +----------+---------+
 |        1 |       1 |
 |        1 |       2 |
 |        2 |       1 |
 |        2 |       2 |
 |        2 |       8 |
 |        3 |       1 |
 |        3 |       2 |
 |        3 |       4 |
 |        4 |       1 |
 |        4 |       2 |
 |        4 |       3 |
 |        4 |       5 |
 |        5 |       1 |
 |        5 |       2 |
 |        5 |       4 |
 |        5 |       6 |
 |        5 |       7 |
 +----------+---------+
```

i have to display the left id = right id in one row
for example

```
for left id 1
left1 | right1 righ 2
for left id 3
left3 | right1 right2 right 4
```

how do i do this ? i have tried joining table , doesn't work

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a simple query to acheive this using GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT left_id, GROUP_CONCAT(right_id SEPARATOR ' ') as rigth_id 
FROM left-right 
GROUP BY left_id;
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot.  i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a reasonably straightforward application of `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY`. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed7e1/2/0)

```
SELECT leftId, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(rightId ORDER BY rightId) rightIds
  FROM bridge
 GROUP BY leftId
```

Comment: exactly as I have answered :)

Comment: thanks a lot. i really appreciate your help